# DropDownList Pierde el estilo

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dropdownlist, updatepanel

Hola tengo un `GridView` en el `RowCommand` llamo un `div` flotante que pierde el estilo al cargar (tiene la opción de búsqueda)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código tengo todo en un `UpdatePanel`, visualmente lo carga pero después de cargar los datos se pierde.

```
 <div id="contenedor" style="display: none">
    <div id="flotante">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSuppliers" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="100%">
                    <h3>REPUESTOS</h3>
                    <asp:Label ID="LblOrden" runat="server" Text="Orden"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="LblComponente" runat="server" Text="Componente"></asp:Label>

                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOrden" runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtComponente" runat="server" Enabled="false" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LblReferencia" runat="server" Text="Referencia"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlReferencia" runat="server" CssClass="chzn-select" AutoPostBack="true" Height="16px" Width="218px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Descripcion" runat="server" Text="Descripcion"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlDescripcion" runat="server" CssClass="chzn-select" AutoPostBack="true" Height="16px" Width="292px"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LblInvenrtario" runat="server" Text="Inventario"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtInventario" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LblCantidad" runat="server" Text="Cantidad"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCantidad" runat="server" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>


                    <asp:Button ID="BtnAgregar" runat="server" Text="Agregar" CssClass="button" />
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnGuardar" runat="server" Text="Guardar" CssClass="button" />

                    <asp:GridView ID="GvProductos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="7" CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="Id,ProductoId" EmptyDataText="No existen registros para mostrar" AllowPaging="true">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Consecutivo" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductoId" HeaderText="Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Referencia" HeaderText="Referencia" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cantidad" HeaderText="Cantidad" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eliminar" ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgRU" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                                        CommandName="Eliminar" ImageUrl="..//Imagenes/Select_16.png" Text="Eliminar" ToolTip="Eliminar" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>

                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnCerrar" runat="server" Text="Cerrar" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="flotante(2)" />
           </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DdlReferencia" EventName="selectedindexchanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DdlDescripcion" EventName="selectedindexchanged" />
            </Triggers>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    <div id="fondo">
    </div>
```

Intente sin el `div` flotante en un fomulario normal solo con los `DropDownList`  el `UpdatePanel`, inicia bien pero después del primer `SelectedIndexChanged` (no muestra el `postback`) se pierde de nuevo todo el estilo de todos los `DropDownList`.

Estoy trabajando con `Asp.net` `Vb` `JavaScript`. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

La solución colocar al final de la pagina:

```
 <script>
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
    function endRequestHandler() {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen({ width: "95%" });
        $(".chzn-container").css({ "width": "95%" });
        $(".chzn-drop").css({ "width": "95%" });
    }
</script>
```